# Three.js SceneExporter getting Uncaught Syntax error

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

So I am trying to export a three.js scene using the SceneExporter, I am just doing this

`var output = new THREE.SceneExporter().parse(scope.renderingEngine.scene);`

When doing this, I get an error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Which occurs at line 750 of SceneExporter.js (which is the line where the JSON gets parsed; `new THREE.SceneExporter().parse(scope.renderingEngine.scene);`)

I don't have anything fancy going on in the scene, just a bunch of geometries. I even tried a scene with no textures in it and still got this error.

Now, if I change that line to simply return the `output` then `JSON.stringify(output)` and save this file, the file's JSON does not validate. I get the following error

```
Parse error on line 1:
"{    \n\t\"metadat
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

And here is line 1-10 of the JSON file

```
"{
    \n\t\"metadata\": {
        \n\t\t\"formatVersion\": 3.2,
        \n\t\t\"type\"\t\t: \"scene\",
        \n\t\t\"generatedBy\"\t: \"SceneExporter\",
        \n\t\t\"objects\": 153,
        \n\t\t\"geometries\": 144,
        \n\t\t\"materials\": 5,
        \n\t\t\"textures\": 1\n\t
    },
    \n\n\t\"urlBaseType\": \"relativeToScene\",
```

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I've had success exporting with the ObjectExporter, maybe it's best to use that for now

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is a "Unexpected token: ILLEGAL" character, probably thrown by your use of "\n\t\t" and others (escape sequences) outside strings. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with escape sequences outside strings, and I don't even know if special characters should be used in JSON.

Also, I see "\" at some of your strings. You can't use "\". You can, however, use "\", that is escape sequence for a "\". Using a single "\" inside a string will give you the "Unexpected token: ILLEGAL" error. "\" must always be followed by a character that makes a valid escape sequence.

Comment: Right, hmm I will post this as an issue at the three.js github repo then, as this seems to be a bug in the way `SceneExporter` constructs its JSON output. I'll accept your answer after looking into it a bit more also, thanks!

Comment: Hey @RohanDeshpande I ran into the same issue and was wondering if you ever found a solution.

Comment: Hmm well I stopped using the `SceneExporter`, I think it's going to become deprecated anyway. Use the `ObjectExporter` instead.