# What is the correct way to edit the vertices of a box geometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I'm editing the vertices of many box geometries to create unique shapes, or to modify the heights of the geometries. It works fine and my scenes look correct (here's an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Z3G.jpg).

However, when I use the `ObjectExporter` and try to load the scene into http://threejs.org/editor/, none of my vertex changes are present. Also when I try to load the `scene.json` file into blender, I get an error (which I can't seem to copy/paste) which lists `KeyError:'vertices'`

Basically, I built a UI to edit the vertices of any box geometry, I save these edits into a matrix, then cross check that matrix when loading the scene. My function looks like this

```
setBaseTileVertices:function()
{
    var scope = this;

    scope.baseTiles.children.forEach(function(tile , t)
    {
        tile.geometry.vertices.forEach(function(vertex , v)
        {
            vertex.x = (tile.userData.vertices[v].x) ? tile.userData.vertices[v].x : vertex.x;
            vertex.y = (tile.userData.vertices[v].y) ? tile.userData.vertices[v].y : vertex.y;
            vertex.z = (tile.userData.vertices[v].z) ? tile.userData.vertices[v].z : vertex.z;
        });
    });
}
```

Is there some other more correct way to edit vertices so that the changes will be recognised by the editor and/or Blender? Am I using the right exporter? I tried used the `THREE.SceneExporter` but got errors as indicated here [Three.js SceneExporter getting Uncaught Syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437657/three-js-sceneexporter-getting-uncaught-syntax-error)

**Edit**

After a bit of investigation, I've seen that in my output JSON, all my box geometries have a similar matrix value, while a square pyramid I created has the correct matrix. I guess I need to update the matrix of each geometry when I modify it. Not too sure how to do that right now but I think I'm on the right track.

**Edit 2**

Well it seems like the matrices for each of my geometries *are* getting updated, so I don't know what's going on now. The pyramid I've created renders fine, but all the box geometries just become flat, with no change to their vertices. Here's an example of how it looks in the editor https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtU0J.jpg note that the bounding box helper knows the height of `baseTiles` which is an `Object3D` that contains each tile. It can only know this if its factoring in their edited vertices.

**Edit 3**

So I've done a test and modified lines 65 - 74 of `ObjectExporter.js` so that they now read

```
} else if ( geometry instanceof THREE.BoxGeometry ) {

    data.type = 'Geometry';
    data.data = geometryExporter.parse( geometry );

    delete data.data.metadata;

    //handleParameters( [ 'width', 'height', 'depth', 'widthSegments', 'heightSegments', 'depthSegments' ] );}
```

Now my level looks correct in terms of shape in the editor https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4sdU.jpg however, seems like my colours or materials are not getting translated over? Everything is black, whereas the +Y faces of the geometries should be coloured green.

As requested here's an example from exporting with the non-edited ObjectExporter

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "version": 4.3,
        "type": "Object",
        "generator": "ObjectExporter"
    },
    "geometries": [{
        "uuid": "25437534-318D-4BB9-9E97-207E390F1A8D",
        "type": "BoxGeometry",
        "width": 64,
        "height": 32,
        "depth": 64
    }],
    "materials": [{
        "type": "MeshFaceMaterial",
        "materials": [{
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "BCFDD918-A69C-4443-806A-A46E356C272C",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 0,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "4969265D-D0B2-4E4A-A60A-AB20EC541FD5",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 0,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "141153C7-C284-4120-9DB9-8386F4C90496",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 6127158,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "B2CDDAE4-B690-41F7-84EC-377C73A7FF21",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 6127158,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "0B21CD67-D4FA-447E-9CA1-56CA755C0872",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 0,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "3089DC93-85E8-42CD-BBE9-2D2A45441AB2",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 0,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }]
    }],
    "object": {
        "uuid": "DE6BC181-ECA5-4B7A-85EA-64387C8B04E1",
        "name": "tile_5_10",
        "type": "Mesh",
        "geometry": "25437534-318D-4BB9-9E97-207E390F1A8D",
        "matrix": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 640, 0, 320, 1]
    }
}
```

And here is an example of the JSON (it's a different object so some values may be different) with my edits (box geometry is parsed as geometry, if I parse the entire scene like this, it gives this result https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4sdU.jpg)

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "version": 4.3,
        "type": "Object",
        "generator": "ObjectExporter"
    },
    "geometries": [{
        "uuid": "4E8EFB7F-8225-4EAA-AE69-C25B23DDE642",
        "type": "Geometry",
        "data": {
            "vertices": [32, 88, 32, 32, 88, -32, 32, -16, 32, 32, -16, -32, -32, 112, -32, -32, 112, 32, -32, -16, -32, -32, -16, 32],
            "normals": [1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1],
            "uvs": [
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
            ],
            "faces": [56, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 4, 6, 5, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 56, 6, 7, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 56, 4, 5, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 56, 5, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 56, 7, 6, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 56, 6, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 56, 5, 7, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 56, 7, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 56, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 56, 3, 6, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5]
        }
    }],
    "materials": [{
        "type": "MeshFaceMaterial",
        "materials": [{
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "E1E6A4F7-06B0-41E2-8131-F2E103D8F7F7",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 0,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "7D777F70-D279-4112-AD6F-FBAFCE1EE9E2",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 0,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "5BBC767A-F130-4F4D-8A5C-489C40D2F698",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 6127158,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "F4F167E2-013E-4A6A-B7F1-80246DD15023",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 6127158,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "CA2ADC0E-F20B-485B-B5D3-DE9B58A733B0",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 0,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }, {
            "metadata": {
                "version": 4.2,
                "type": "material",
                "generator": "MaterialExporter"
            },
            "uuid": "7BC988E6-B3A0-4BF2-B360-1C0F4976436F",
            "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
            "color": 0,
            "opacity": 1,
            "transparent": false,
            "wireframe": false
        }]
    }],
    "object": {
        "uuid": "809D131E-3F34-4DCB-8304-EDCA144BF1A6",
        "name": "tile_9_9",
        "type": "Mesh",
        "geometry": "4E8EFB7F-8225-4EAA-AE69-C25B23DDE642",
        "matrix": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 576, 0, 576, 1]
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `tile.geometry` and instance of `THREE.Geometry` or `THREE.BufferGeometry`?

Comment: It's a box geometry, but yes I think you've asked the right question. I'm going to test with the new OBJ.Exporter from the dev branch because it seems like that might be more appropriate.

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of the output JSON showing the relevant object(s)?

Comment: Yep! And yes this is part of the problem as the current (r68) `ObjectExporter` doesn't seem to include vertices, uvs or normals data for a box geometry, only parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bunch of research, I've found that currently, the correct way to do this is to convert your `BoxGeometry` objects to `BufferGeometry` or regular `Geometry` objects. You can do this after editing their vertices.

So something like this

```
var box = new THREE.BoxGeometry(64 , 32 , 64);

box.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
box.vertices[0].y = 128;
box.vertices[1].y = 128;

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(box);

//or alternatively

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.merge(box);
```

Now, if you export the object using the `ObjectExporter` it should load into http://threejs.org/editor fine.

Comment: `box.vertices` is undefined for me. Did anyone had similiar problem?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes I am getting this issue as well. I believe it has to do with update to the library. Trying to find some resources to resolve this myself.

Comment: @Konrad they have been replaced with `box.attributes.position`