# Export modified planes geometry as JSON, using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I modify a plane geometry's vertices to create new geometry. 
But when I export the geometry it's still a plane geometry and my modified vertices is not included.

How do I export my new geometry as JSON including every changes?

Here's my code:

```
var seg = 5;
var dim = 70;
var zScale = 20;
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(dim,  dim, seg, seg );
var index = 0;

for (var gridY = 0; gridY < seg; gridY++) {
    for (var gridX = 0; gridX < seg; gridX++) {
        var z = Math.random() * zScale;
        geometry.vertices[index].z = z;
        index++;
    }
}

geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
var expJson = geometry.toJSON();
console.log(expJson);
```

My exported data looks like this:

```
{
    height: 70
    heightSegments: 5
    metadata: {
        generator: "Geometry.toJSON"
        type: "PlaneGeometry"
    },
    version: 4.4
    type: "PlaneGeometry"
    uuid: "5F071B03-15EA-43CE-B4B3-4944E13D781C"
    width: 70
    widthSegments: 5
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I use. If someone has a better one please post it. But this works for me and is quite neat.

I just add a new geometry object and copies the verticies and faces from the plane geometry.

```
var seg = 5;
var dim = 70;
var zScale = 20;
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(dim,  dim, seg, seg );
var index = 0;

for (var gridY = 0; gridY < seg; gridY++) {
    for (var gridX = 0; gridX < seg; gridX++) {
        var z = Math.random() * zScale;
        geometry.vertices[index].z = z;
        index++;
    }
}

geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

// The fix start ---
var neoGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
neoGeo.vertices = geometry.vertices;
neoGeo.faces = geometry.faces;
neoGeo.faceVertexUvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs;
// The fix end ---

var expJson = neoGeo.toJSON(); //Export json from the new geometry object
console.log(expJson);
```

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5483 for an explanation why you need to convert to `THREE.Geometry` or `THREE.BufferGeometry` if you want the raw data.

---

And a simpler way to do this is (*from  [Export ThreeJS Geometry to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26478256/128165)*)

```
var rawGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
var expJson = rawGeometry.toJSON();
```

or

```
var rawGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
rawGeometry.merge( geometry );
var expJson = rawGeometry.toJSON();
```